# Вызов функции c++

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

В чём различие между двумя инструкциями?

```
 void func() {}
 int main()
 {
    func(); // <--
    func;   // <--
 }
```

Comment: Первая вызов. А вторая смысла в этом контексте не несет, т.к. это просто адрес функции, его можно было бы присвоить какой нибудь переменной, например

Comment: @Mike спс))))))

Comment: @Mike оформи как ответ

Comment: @dDevil Да там уже есть ответ. и он продолжает улучшатся ...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7):

Первая строчка вызывает функцию, а вторая ничего не делает.

Вторую строчку можно сравнить со следующим кодом:

```
int n = 0;
n;
```

Т.е. это выражение, результатом которого является само выражение. В случае с `n` это значение переменной `n`, а в Вашем случае это адрес функции `func`.
Можно Ваш пример дописать следующим образом:

```
auto f = func;   // <--
f();
```

Здесь, мы скопировали адрес `func`(этот то, что было у Вас, но мы дополнили присвоением), а потом мы вызываем `func`, косвенно, через `f`.

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы было более ясно, давайте разберемся последовательно с каждым предложением программы.

Данное предложение

```
void func() {}
```

является объявлением функции с типом `void()`, то есть функции, которая не имеет параметров и имеет тип возвращаемого значения `void`.

Данное предложение

```
func(); // <--
```

вызывает эту функцию. Функция ничего не делает и не имеет побочных эффектов. Поэтому компилятор может выкинуть это предложение из сгенерированного объектного кода.

Данное предложение

```
func;   // <--
```

состоит из выражения, в котором используется имя функции. Оно преобразуется в указатель на функцию типа `void ( * )()`. И опять-таки данное предложени не имеет побочных эффектов и может быть проигнорировано компилятором при генерации объектного кода.

Вы могли бы получить более наглядный пример, если бы функция выполняла какие-то действия. Например, если бы вы объявили функцию как

```
void func() { std::cout << "I'm called" << std::cout; }
```

то результатом выполнения данного предложения

```
func(); // <--
```

был бы вывод на консоль строки

```
I'm called
```

А результат этого предложения

```
func;   // <--
```

не изменился бы, так как это выражение ничего не вычисляет и, как я уже сказал, не имеет побочных эффектов.

Другой наглядный пример. Рассмотрите программу

```
#include <iostream>

int f1() { return 10; }
int f2() { return 20; }

int main()
{
    int ( *pf[] )() = { f1, f2 };
    int a1[] = { f1(), f2() };
    int a2[] = { pf[0](), pf[1]() };

    for ( int x : a1 ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for ( int x : a2 ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

В этой программе объявляются две функции `f1` и `f2`.

Затем объявляется массив указателей на эти функции

```
int ( *pf[] )() = { f1, f2 };
```

В качестве инициализаторов массива используются выражения `f1` и `f2`, которые преобразуются в указатели на эти функции. То есть сами функции не вызываются и не выполняются. Берутся их адреса, и этими адресами инициализируются элементы массива `pf`.

Затем объявляется массив целых чисел  `a1`.

```
int a1[] = { f1(), f2() };
```

В качестве инициализаторов массива используются вызовы функций `f1` и `f2`. Результатом вызова первой функции будет значение `10`, а вызова второй функции - значение `20`, Поэтому массив `a1` инициализируется значениями `10` и `20`.

Затем объявляется второй массив

```
int a2[] = { pf[0](), pf[1]() };
```

Он инициализируется результатами вызовов тех же самых функций, но с использованием указателей на эти функции, которые были занесены в элементы массива `pf`.  Эти вызовы эквивалентны что для инициализации первого массива `a1`, и что для инициализации второго массива `a2`. Поэтому вывод на консоль будет одним и тем же для обоих циклов

```
10 20 
10 20
```

Еще один пример программы, которая наглядно демонстрирует преобразование имени функции, используемой в выражениях, в указатель на функцию, и связанный с этим эффект, о котором даже квалифицированные программисты не подозревают.

Итак, как было сказано, если у вас есть какая-то функция, как, например,

```
void f() { std::cout << "I'm called!" << std::endl; }
```

то использование ее имени в выражении

```
f;
```

приводит к преобразованию ее в указатель на нее саму. То есть это выражение имеет тип

```
void ( * )()
```

Разыменование указателя приводит к ссылке на саму функцию. То есть если вы напишите

```
*f;
```

То оператор разыменования, примененный к выражению `f` , снова даст, грубо говоря, саму функцию (`lvalue на f`) . И сразу же это выражение снова преобразуется в указатель на функцию, так как выражение `*f` не используется в операции, где  требуется сама функция.

Поэтому данные записи

```
f;
*f;
**f;
```

и т.д. все они являются выражениями, которые имеют тип указателей на функцию `f`

Вот соответствующая программа, которая это демонстрирует

```
#include <iostream>

void f() { std::cout << "I'm called!" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    f();
    ( *f )();
    ( **f )();
    ( ***f )();
    ( ****f )();
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль будет

```
I'm called!
I'm called!
I'm called!
I'm called!
I'm called!
```

Количество допустимых разыменований, то есть применения оператора `*` ограничивается лишь возможностями компилятора.

Поэтому если у вас на работе производительность программиста оценивается количеством знаков написанного им кода, то вы можете использовать этот прием вызова функции для увеличения этого значения.:)